# IndexError: Array slice indices must have static start/stop/step to be used with NumPy indexing syntax

Tags: python, jax

I want to write a pca function in jax, but there is a problem when compiling with jax.jit. Here it says `IndexError: Array slice indices must have static start/stop/step to be used with NumPy indexing syntax. Found slice(None, Traced<ShapedArray(int32[], weak_type=True)>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, None). To index a statically sized array at a dynamic position, try lax.dynamic_slice/dynamic_update_slice (JAX does not support dynamically sized arrays within JIT compiled functions).`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 106
    101 result = _fit_full(x_centered, 2)
    103 sim  = spsim.Simulator.simple(
    104     3, spu_pb2.ProtocolKind.ABY3, spu_pb2.FieldType.FM64
    105 )
--> 106 result = spsim.sim_jax(sim, _fit_full)(x_centered, 2)
    107 # result = spsim.sim_jax(sim, fit_and_transform)(x_centered, 2)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spu/utils/simulation.py:152, in sim_jax.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    149 def outputNameGen(out_flat):
    150     return [f'out{idx}' for idx in range(len(out_flat))]
--> 152 executable, output = spu_fe.compile(
    153     spu_fe.Kind.JAX,
    154     fun,
    155     args,
    156     kwargs,
    157     in_names,
    158     in_vis,
    159     outputNameGen,
    160     static_argnums=static_argnums,
    161 )
    163 wrapper.pphlo = executable.code.decode("utf-8")
    165 out_flat = sim(executable, *args_flat)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spu/utils/frontend.py:112, in compile(kind, fn, args, kwargs, input_names, input_vis, outputNameGen, static_argnums)
    108 import jax
    110 patches = _patch_jax()
--> 112 ir_text, output = _jax_compilation(fn, static_argnums, args, kwargs)
    114 _restore_jax_patch(patches)
    116 output_flat, _ = jax.tree_util.tree_flatten(output)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cachetools/__init__.py:737, in cached.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    735 except KeyError:
    736     pass  # key not found
--> 737 v = func(*args, **kwargs)
    738 try:
    739     cache[k] = v

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spu/utils/frontend.py:41, in _jax_compilation(fn, static_argnums, args, kwargs)
     37 @cached(cache=LRUCache(maxsize=128), key=_jax_compilation_key)
     38 def _jax_compilation(fn: Callable, static_argnums, args: List, kwargs: Dict):
     39     import jax
---> 41     cfn, output = jax.xla_computation(
     42         fn, return_shape=True, static_argnums=static_argnums, backend="interpreter"
     43     )(*args, **kwargs)
     44     return cfn.as_serialized_hlo_module_proto(), output

    [... skipping hidden 6 frame]

Cell In[21], line 58, in _fit_full(x, n_components)
     55 U, S, Vt = jax.scipy.linalg.svd(x, full_matrices=False)
     57 # Compute the explained variance
---> 58 explained_variance = (S[:n_components] ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)
     60 # Return the transformation matrix
     61 A = Vt[:n_components]

    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py:3908, in _rewriting_take(arr, idx, indices_are_sorted, unique_indices, mode, fill_value)
   3905       return lax.dynamic_index_in_dim(arr, idx, keepdims=False)
   3907 treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx = _split_index_for_jit(idx, arr.shape)
-> 3908 return _gather(arr, treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx, indices_are_sorted,
   3909                unique_indices, mode, fill_value)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py:3917, in _gather(arr, treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx, indices_are_sorted, unique_indices, mode, fill_value)
   3914 def _gather(arr, treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx, indices_are_sorted,
   3915             unique_indices, mode, fill_value):
   3916   idx = _merge_static_and_dynamic_indices(treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx)
-> 3917   indexer = _index_to_gather(shape(arr), idx)  # shared with _scatter_update
   3918   y = arr
   3920   if fill_value is not None:

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py:4169, in _index_to_gather(x_shape, idx, normalize_indices)
   4160 if not _all(_is_slice_element_none_or_constant(elt)
   4161             for elt in (start, stop, step)):
   4162   msg = ("Array slice indices must have static start/stop/step to be used "
   4163          "with NumPy indexing syntax. "
   4164          f"Found slice({start}, {stop}, {step}). "
   (...)
   4167          "dynamic_update_slice (JAX does not support dynamically sized "
   4168          "arrays within JIT compiled functions).")
-> 4169   raise IndexError(msg)
   4170 if not core.is_constant_dim(x_shape[x_axis]):
   4171   msg = ("Cannot use NumPy slice indexing on an array dimension whose "
   4172          f"size is not statically known ({x_shape[x_axis]}). "
   4173          "Try using lax.dynamic_slice/dynamic_update_slice")

IndexError: Array slice indices must have static start/stop/step to be used with NumPy indexing syntax. Found slice(None, Traced<ShapedArray(int32[], weak_type=True)>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, None). To index a statically sized array at a dynamic position, try lax.dynamic_slice/dynamic_update_slice (JAX does not support dynamically sized arrays within JIT compiled functions).
```

Here spu is just an emulator, and when I changed it to jax.jit, I got the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 101
     94 X_recovered = recover(state, X_pca)
     97 # def fit_and_transform(x,n_components=2):
     98 #     state = fit(x,n_components)
     99 #     return transform(state,x)
--> 101 result = jax.jit(_fit_full)(x_centered, 2)
    103 # sim  = spsim.Simulator.simple(
    104 #     3, spu_pb2.ProtocolKind.ABY3, spu_pb2.FieldType.FM64
    105 # )
    106 # result = spsim.sim_jax(sim, _fit_full)(x_centered, 2)
    107 # result = spsim.sim_jax(sim, fit_and_transform)(x_centered, 2)

    [... skipping hidden 12 frame]

Cell In[22], line 58, in _fit_full(x, n_components)
     55 U, S, Vt = jax.scipy.linalg.svd(x, full_matrices=False)
     57 # Compute the explained variance
---> 58 explained_variance = (S[:n_components] ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)
     60 # Return the transformation matrix
     61 A = Vt[:n_components]

    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py:3908, in _rewriting_take(arr, idx, indices_are_sorted, unique_indices, mode, fill_value)
   3905       return lax.dynamic_index_in_dim(arr, idx, keepdims=False)
   3907 treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx = _split_index_for_jit(idx, arr.shape)
-> 3908 return _gather(arr, treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx, indices_are_sorted,
   3909                unique_indices, mode, fill_value)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py:3917, in _gather(arr, treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx, indices_are_sorted, unique_indices, mode, fill_value)
   3914 def _gather(arr, treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx, indices_are_sorted,
   3915             unique_indices, mode, fill_value):
   3916   idx = _merge_static_and_dynamic_indices(treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx)
-> 3917   indexer = _index_to_gather(shape(arr), idx)  # shared with _scatter_update
   3918   y = arr
   3920   if fill_value is not None:

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py:4169, in _index_to_gather(x_shape, idx, normalize_indices)
   4160 if not _all(_is_slice_element_none_or_constant(elt)
   4161             for elt in (start, stop, step)):
   4162   msg = ("Array slice indices must have static start/stop/step to be used "
   4163          "with NumPy indexing syntax. "
   4164          f"Found slice({start}, {stop}, {step}). "
   (...)
   4167          "dynamic_update_slice (JAX does not support dynamically sized "
   4168          "arrays within JIT compiled functions).")
-> 4169   raise IndexError(msg)
   4170 if not core.is_constant_dim(x_shape[x_axis]):
   4171   msg = ("Cannot use NumPy slice indexing on an array dimension whose "
   4172          f"size is not statically known ({x_shape[x_axis]}). "
   4173          "Try using lax.dynamic_slice/dynamic_update_slice")

IndexError: Array slice indices must have static start/stop/step to be used with NumPy indexing syntax. Found slice(None, Traced<ShapedArray(int32[], weak_type=True)>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, None). To index a statically sized array at a dynamic position, try lax.dynamic_slice/dynamic_update_slice (JAX does not support dynamically sized arrays within JIT compiled functions).
```

Here's the original code

```
from functools import partial
from typing import NamedTuple

import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

import unittest
import json
import jax.numpy as jnp
import spu.utils.simulation as spsim
import spu.spu_pb2 as spu_pb2  # 


class PCAState(NamedTuple):
    components: jax.Array
    means: jax.Array
    explained_variance: jax.Array


def transform(state, x):
    x = x - state.means
    return jnp.dot(x, jnp.transpose(state.components))


def recover(state, x):
    return jnp.dot(x, state.components) + state.means


def fit(x, n_components, solver="full", rng=None):
    if solver == "full":
        return _fit_full(x, n_components)
    elif solver == "randomized":
        if rng is None:
            rng = jax.random.PRNGKey(n_components)
        return _fit_randomized(x, n_components, rng)
    else:
        raise ValueError("solver parameter is not correct")

# @partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def fit_and_transform(x, n_components=2):
    state = fit(x, n_components)
    return transform(state, x)


# @partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=["n_components"])
def _fit_full(x, n_components):
    n_samples, n_features = x.shape

    # Subtract the mean of the input data
    means = x.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)
    x = x - means

    # Factorize the data matrix with singular value decomposition.
    U, S, Vt = jax.scipy.linalg.svd(x, full_matrices=False)

    # Compute the explained variance
    explained_variance = (S[:n_components] ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)

    # Return the transformation matrix
    A = Vt[:n_components]
    return PCAState(components=A, means=means, explained_variance=explained_variance)


def _fit_randomized(x, n_components, rng, n_iter=5):
    """Randomized PCA based on Halko et al [https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1007.5510]."""
    n_samples, n_features = x.shape
    means = jnp.mean(x, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    x = x - means

    # Generate n_features normal vectors of the given size
    size = jnp.minimum(2 * n_components, n_features)
    Q = jax.random.normal(rng, shape=(n_features, size))

    def step_fn(q, _):
        q, _ = jax.scipy.linalg.lu(x @ q, permute_l=True)
        q, _ = jax.scipy.linalg.lu(x.T @ q, permute_l=True)
        return q, None

    Q, _ = jax.lax.scan(step_fn, init=Q, xs=None, length=n_iter)
    Q, _ = jax.scipy.linalg.qr(x @ Q, mode="economic")
    B = Q.T @ x

    _, S, Vt = jax.scipy.linalg.svd(B, full_matrices=False)

    explained_variance = (S[:n_components] ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)
    A = Vt[:n_components]
    return PCAState(components=A, means=means, explained_variance=explained_variance)

X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
x_centered = X - X.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)
state = fit(x_centered,n_components=2)
X_pca = transform(state, x_centered)
X_recovered = recover(state, X_pca)


# def fit_and_transform(x,n_components=2):
#     state = fit(x,n_components)
#     return transform(state,x)

result = jax.jit(_fit_full)(x_centered, 2)

# sim  = spsim.Simulator.simple(
#     3, spu_pb2.ProtocolKind.ABY3, spu_pb2.FieldType.FM64
# )
# result = spsim.sim_jax(sim, _fit_full)(x_centered, 2)
# result = spsim.sim_jax(sim, fit_and_transform)(x_centered, 2)
```

When I use lax.dynamic_slice, I still get an error:

```
Cell In[23], line 59, in _fit_full(x, n_components)
     55 U, S, Vt = jax.scipy.linalg.svd(x, full_matrices=False)
     57 # Compute the explained variance
---> 59 explained_variance = (jax.lax.dynamic_slice(S, (0,), (n_components,)) ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)
     61 # Return the transformation matrix
     62 A = Vt[:n_components]

    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/sf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py:2039, in canonicalize_shape(shape, context)
   2037 except TypeError:
   2038   pass
-> 2039 raise _invalid_shape_error(shape, context)

TypeError: Shapes must be 1D sequences of concrete values of integer type, got (Traced<ShapedArray(int32[], weak_type=True)>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>,).
If using `jit`, try using `static_argnums` or applying `jit` to smaller subfunctions.
The error occurred while tracing the function _fit_full at /var/folders/1b/fb42jjtx1b707mz9njgqkd1c0000gp/T/ipykernel_93715/3940440843.py:47 for jit. This concrete value was not available in Python because it depends on the value of the argument n_components.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: @jakevdp Hi, jakevdp! Could you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Inside transformations like `jit` or `vmap`, JAX array shapes must be static (see [JAX Sharp Bits: Dynamic Shapes](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#dynamic-shapes) for some discussion of this).

In your code, you are creating arrays of size `n_components`, and this means that `n_components` must be marked as a static argument in `jit` or other JAX transformations. You should be able to achieve this using the `static_argnames` argument that is commented-out at one point in your code:

```py
result = jax.jit(_fit_full, static_argnames=['num_components'])(x_centered, 2)
```

A note on `dynamic_slice`: this does not let you create arrays of dynamic shape, but rather allows you to extract a statically-shaped slice at a dynamic location within the array, so it's not relevant to your case.