# "Array slice indices must have static start/stop/step" when `jax.lax.scan`ning involving an Equinox model

Tags: python, jax

The Equinox model looks like this:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp, jax.random as jrnd
import equinox as eqx

class Model(eqx.Module):
    lags: list[int]
    linear: eqx.Module

    def __init__(self, lags: list[int]=[22, 5, 1], *, key: jrnd.PRNGKeyArray):
        self.lags = lags
        self.linear = eqx.nn.Linear(len(lags), 1, key=key)

    def __call__(self, x, key=None):
        x_new = jnp.array([
            x[-lag:].mean() for lag in self.lags
        ])
        return self.linear(x_new)
```

Notice how I have `x[-lag:].mean()` inside `__call__`, which apparently causes issues.

The rest of my code does something like this:

```
@eqx.filter_value_and_grad
def loss(model: eqx.Module, X: jax.Array, y: jax.Array):
    y_pred = eqx.filter_vmap(model)(X)
    return ((y_pred - y)**2).mean()

@eqx.filter_jit
def scanner(model: eqx.Module, _):
    loss_val, _ = loss(model, X, y)
    return model, loss_val
    
key = jrnd.PRNGKey(5)
X = jrnd.normal(key, (50, 22))
y = jrnd.uniform(key, (X.shape[0], ))

model = Model(key=key)
print(model)

print("`vmap` works:")
print(eqx.filter_jit(loss)(model, X, y))

print("`scan` errors:")
jax.lax.scan(scanner, model, jnp.arange(5))
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

--------------------

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_question_repro.py", line 40, in <module>
    jax.lax.scan(scanner, model, jnp.arange(5))
  File "_question_repro.py", line 26, in scanner
    loss_val, _ = loss(model, X, y)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "_question_repro.py", line 21, in loss
    y_pred = jax.vmap(model)(X)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "_question_repro.py", line 14, in __call__
    x_new = jnp.array([
                      ^
  File "_question_repro.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    x[-lag:].mean() for lag in self.lags
    ~^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/array_methods.py", line 723, in op
    return getattr(self.aval, f"_{name}")(self, *args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py", line 4153, in _rewriting_take
    return _gather(arr, treedef, static_idx, dynamic_idx, indices_are_sorted,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py", line 4162, in _gather
    indexer = _index_to_gather(shape(arr), idx)  # shared with _scatter_update
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py", line 4414, in _index_to_gather
    raise IndexError(msg)
IndexError: Array slice indices must have static start/stop/step to be used with NumPy indexing syntax. Found slice(Traced<ShapedArray(int32[], weak_type=True)>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=2/0)>, None, None). To index a statically sized array at a dynamic position, try lax.dynamic_slice/dynamic_update_slice (JAX does not support dynamically sized arrays within JIT compiled functions).
```

The error message suggests that I'm trying to "index a statically sized array at a dynamic position", but I'm not: `self.lags` is a list of integers that's supposed to be constant.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76636892), "Inside transformations like `jit` or `vmap`, JAX array shapes must be static". Sure, but then the `jit` and `vmap` calls in my code shouldn't have worked, but they did. The only thing that *doesn't* work is `jax.lax.scan(scanner, model, jnp.arange(5))`.

What's special about `jax.lax.scan` that makes my code produce this error? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After posting this question, I almost immediately discovered a solution.

Mark `lags` as [`equinox.field(static=True)`](https://docs.kidger.site/equinox/api/module/advanced_fields/#equinox.field), which means that "the field should *not* interact with any JAX transform at all (by making it part of the PyTree structure rather than a leaf)":

```
class Model(eqx.Module):
    lags: list[int] = eqx.field(static=True)
    linear: eqx.Module

    ... # Other code unchanged
```

Now `jax.lax.scan` works fine:

```
>>> jax.lax.scan(scanner, model, jnp.arange(5))
(Model(
  lags=[22, 5, 1],
  linear=Linear(
    weight=f32[1,3],
    bias=f32[1],
    in_features=3,
    out_features=1,
    use_bias=True
  )
), Array([0.34578627, 0.34578627, 0.34578627, 0.34578627, 0.34578627],      dtype=float32))
>>>
```